# Mongodb set element in collection with existing elements

Tags: mongodb

I have an collection entry:

{ 
first_name: "Chris",
last_name: "XXXX"
}

I want to add a new element called "full_name" which consists of "first_name" and "last_name", so I end up with.

{
first_name: "Chris",
last_name: "XXXX",
full_name: "Chris XXXX",
}

Is this possible with a normal mongo update / upsert query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. You can not use the fields from the query in mongodb. So you have to use foreach.

```
db.a.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.full_name = doc.first_name + ' ' + doc.last_name;
  db.a.save(doc);
});
```

And I remember I already answered the question similar to this, but I am not able to find it.